# Square Picasso not displaying images from disc cache

Tags: android, caching, image-caching, picasso

Downloading images and caching in memory is working. 
But there are no displayed image when I turn off internet connection. I expect that there should be displayed images from disc cache. I have checked that images are downloaded to /data/data//cache/picasso-cache

When I debugging there is exeception in
BitmapHunter, method run():

*java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.111 (port 8080) after 15000ms: connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)*

I did not setup disc caching in my project in any way, I have only added new maven dependency "okhttp" except picasso

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.picasso</groupId>
        <artifactId>picasso</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: U did not setup disk cache,then how image will be stored in external SD card?

Comment: picasso have default storage configuration

Comment: The Cache Headers may expired.

Comment: The creator, Jake, says here (http://stackoverflow.com/a/19164416/243709) that Picasso depends on the expiration time set in the HTTP header, and doesn't give you any control over the decision which image to pick