# Picasso: URL cache expiration

Tags: android, caching, cache-control, picasso

I am developing android app that shows an image from URL. For this, I'm using [Picasso library](http://square.github.io/picasso/) and it is working nicely. However, I think its caching time period depends on the **headers** of the image URL.

I have set `Cache-Control:max-age=0` for image URL header and Picasso is only caching for few days and I want to store these images more than few days. Please help me find out the solution.

Comment: Have you found any solution to this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android + Picasso: changing URL cache expiration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132377/android-picasso-changing-url-cache-expiration)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132377/android-picasso-changing-url-cache-expiration) there is no way to tell picasso to use some custom cache period.