# Picasso - keeping images on disk

Tags: android, image, caching, picasso, okhttp

I'm using Picasso to download images in my app. My understanding is that it uses a http client (HttpResponseCache or OkHttpClient) to cache these images on disk.

Without knowing much about either of these libraries, is it possible to mark certain images as permanent? In other words, I would like to download an image and guarantee that it will be available offline.

Thinking about it, I couldn't really have the disk cache go over a certain size, so I guess what I really need is to remove the TTL on the image url and allow the cache to remove images in a first in first out scenario.

In that case, can I control which image will be deleted first (by using a timestamp based on accessed, rather than downloaded)?

### Update

Based on the answer from this SO question:

[Android + Picasso: changing URL cache expiration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132377/android-picasso-changing-url-cache-expiration)

So this answers the first part of the question - we can control the TTL through the server.

After talking to a colleague, he pointed out that the http client should take into account how frequently an image is accessed (in addition to the TTL). So hopefully I don't have to worry about this either.

That leaves me with one question. I know which images I don't need anymore, can I remove an image from the disk cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate the elements in OkHttp's disk cache, and call `Iterator.remove()` to get rid of the ones you don't want.

http://square.github.io/okhttp/javadoc/com/squareup/okhttp/Cache.html#urls--

Comment: How do I get access to the cache object from Picasso? Do I have to override the OkHttpDownloader class to gain access to the getClient() method?

Comment: Never mind, I realised that I could pass up OkHttpClient to OkHttpDownloader :P

Comment: Does Picasso look at cache headers to determine how long to cache for?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to extend Picasso's default cache and create a custom Picasso instance to use it:

1. Extend [LruCache](https://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/com/squareup/picasso/LruCache.html)
2. Override the `void set(String key, Bitmap bitmap)` method to do what you describe (adding timestamp, etc.). Check out the original source code [here](https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/LruCache.java).
3. Make sure that the original `trimToSize` method is never called by `set` (and `clearKeyUri` for that matter), and write your own to check for the timestamp etc to get the behavior you describe
4. Create a custom Picasso instance with your custom cache like this:

`Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(context).memoryCache(cache).build(); Picasso.setSingletonInstance(picasso);`

Where `cache` is an instance of your custom `LruCache` class

Comment: Wouldn't this affect the memory cache, rather than the disk cache?

Answer (score 0):

when you want to store the images on the disk you should use the okhttpdownloader

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .cache(new Cache(getCacheDir(), Integer.MAX_VALUE))
                .build();
        Picasso build = new Picasso.Builder(this)
                .downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(client))
                .build();
        Picasso.setSingletonInstance(build);
```