# Picasso android disk cache for offline use?

Tags: android, caching, picasso

Hi i am trying to download and store the images retrieved using piccaso android and increase the disk cache but unfortunately, when i load the images up, exit the app, go offline and then relaunch the app, Picasso doesn't seem to load the images its supposed to have cached?

Here is my code:

```
  var picascoBuilder = Picasso.Builder(view.context)
            .downloader(OkHttp3Downloader(view.context, Integer.MAX_VALUE.toLong()))
            .build()
    picascoBuilder.load(offer.imgUrl).into(view.productImage)
```

Answer (score 0):

Define those this variables on your class

```
private static final int OFFLINE = 1 << 2;
private static final int NO_STORE = 1 << 1;
private static final int NO_CACHE = 1 << 0;
```

use this line for offline mode:

```
 var picascoBuilder = Picasso.Builder(view.context)
        .downloader(OkHttp3Downloader(view.context, OFFLINE))
        .build()
```

and this line for online mode :

```
var picascoBuilder = Picasso.Builder(view.context)
        .downloader(OkHttp3Downloader(view.context, 0))
        .build()
```

made this conclusion from here : https://github.com/JakeWharton/picasso2-okhttp3-downloader/blob/master/src/test/java/com/jakewharton/picasso/OkHttp3DownloaderTest.java

Comment: What does the 1 <<2 represent? Is that not the disk cache size?

Comment: They designates the policy to use for network requests: https://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/com/squareup/picasso/NetworkPolicy.html

Comment: It says it will skip the network request but does it only skip the network request if the data was cached already?

Comment: It will skip the network request in both cases with OFFLINE option, you need to separate the cases (online mode and offline)

Comment: Maybe there's a better way to do this i don't know

Comment: There has to be a better way of doing this? why cant it auto do it? instead of manually setting either offline or online?

Comment: Have you tried without the .download() ? i just did test it seems working without it

Comment: what do u mean without download? we need that so we can use okhttp3 to download and cache it?

Comment: Picasso cashes automatically loaded images, i just tryed this picassoBuilder = new Picasso.Builder(MainActivity.this).build(); picassoBuilder.load(uri).into(imageView)) , opened the app on online, and closed the app, and went offline and the image was displayed

Comment: How long does it cache for? Documents on this library is all over the place

Comment: I don't know, sorry :/

Comment: i just tried without download() and still it doesnt cache the images for offline use. are u sure it worked for u? make sure u kill the app

Comment: Yes 100% sure, Here is the code i used `imageView = findViewById(R.id.imgTest);
        uri =  Uri.parse( "https://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Simplest-Responsive-jQuery-Image-Lightbox-Plugin-simple-lightbox.jpg" );
        picassoBuilder = new Picasso.Builder(MainActivity.this).build();
        picassoBuilder.load(uri).into(imageView);`

Comment: Yea my code is very similar to your except i dont use a uri parser i just pit the img url

Comment: is it because i have the code wrapped inside a typical bindView in a recyclerview?

Comment: I don't think it's beacause of that, are you using a recent version of Picasso ?  does the images shows when you go online ?

Comment: Yea using 2.7xxxx

Comment: no Joy at all with this. It would sometimes cache to disk but not for long . as soon as i navigate to another screen and back, it loses the cached data and it doesnt cache all items in my recyclerview, Only maybe 2-3 that are visible on the screen

Comment: yes i have tried on pixel 2, one plus 5, nexus 4 nd now the s9+. same behaviour. It doesnt cache it for offline use

Comment: Check the last answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132377/android-picasso-changing-url-cache-expiration/19164416#19164416 maybe it can help

Comment: Or maybe the server from where you are retreiving the images does not provide accurate headers to ensure proper caching